# Boto3 Write to DynamoDB from AWS Glue, Unhashable Type: 'dict'

Tags: pyspark, boto3, aws-glue

I am attempting to use the boto3 module in PySpark (AWS Glue ETL job) to load a dataframe into DynamoDB but am being met with the error:

```
Parameter validation failed: Invalid type for parameter Item, value: set(["{u'ecosystemName': u'animals', u'regionalCenter': u'center', u'dataExtractedTimestamp': u'20190502T13:12:11.111Z'}"]), type: <type 'set'>, valid types: <type 'dict'> Could not write to the Audit Table for regional center:
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue and explain why it is happening?  I'd like to understand the root of the issue.

Here is my current code.  Please note that there will ever only be a single row in this data frame.  The SQL used below is fake data for testing only.

```
        try:
            timestamp_sql = """select
                                'animals' as ecosystemName,
                                '20190502T13:12:11.111Z' as dataExtractedTimestamp,
                        'center' as regionalCenter
                                """
            # Make a data frame from SQL
            audit_data_frame=spark.sql(timestamp_sql)

            # Write the joined dynamic frame out to a datasink
            dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb','us-west-2')

            table = dynamodb.Table(args['DynamoDBTable2Name'])

            audit_data_frame_prep = json.loads(audit_data_frame.toJSON().first())

            print(audit_data_frame_prep)

            table.put_item( Item = { "{}".format(audit_data_frame_prep) } )

            print('Audit trail successfully written for ' + regional_center + '.')


        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print('Could not write to the Audit Table for regional center: ' + regional_center + '.')
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Dang, 5 minute rule strikes again...

It was in my put_item call. I had the extra brackets there, effectively rendering the JSON invalid.  This change solves my issue:

```
table.put_item( Item = audit_data_frame_prep )
```